# run two python scripts with docker compose

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

My folder structure looked like this:

[image]

My Dockerfile looked like this:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

WORKDIR /src

COPY src/requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY src/ .

CMD [ "python", "main.py"]
```

When I ran these commands:

```
docker build --tag FinTechExplained_Python_Docker .
docker run free
```

my `main.py`file ran and gave the correct print statements as well. Now, I have added another file `tests.py` in the `src` folder. I want to run the `tests.py` first and then `main.py`.

I tried modifying the `cmd`within my docker file like this:

```
CMD [ "python", "test.py"]  && [ "python", "main.py"]
```

but then it gives me the print statements from only the first `test.py`file.

I read about docker-compose and added this `docker-compose.yml` file to the root folder:

```
version: '3'

services:
  main:
    image: free
    command: >
      /bin/sh -c 'python tests.py'

  main:
    image: free
    command: >
      /bin/sh -c 'python main.py'
```

then I changed my docker file by removing the cmd:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

WORKDIR /src

COPY src/requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY src/ .
```

Then I ran the following commands:

```
docker compose build
docker compose run tests
docker compose run main
```

When I run these commands separately, I get the correct print statements for both `tests`and `main`. However, I am not sure if I am using `docker-compose`correctly or not.

- Am I supposed to run both scripts separately? Or is there a way to run one after another using a single docker command?
- How is my Dockerfile supposed to look like if I am running the python scripts from the `docker-compose.yml` instead?

Edit:

Ideally looking for solutions based on **docker-compose**

Answer (score 1):

In the Bourne shell, in general, you can run two commands in sequence by putting `&&` between them.  It sounds like you're already aware of this.

```sh
# without Docker, at a normal shell prompt
python test.py && python main.py
```

The Dockerfile `CMD` has two syntactic forms.  The JSON-array form does not run a shell, and so it is slightly more efficient and has slightly more consistent escaping rules.  If it's not a JSON array then Docker automatically runs it via a shell.  So for your use you can use the shell form:

```sh
CMD python test.py && python main.py
```

In comments to other answers you ask about providing this as an override in the `docker-compose.yml` file.  Compose will not normally run a shell for you, so you need to explicitly specify it as part of the `command:` override.

```yaml
command: /bin/sh -c 'python test.py && python main.py'
```

Your Dockerfile should generally specify a `CMD` and the `docker-compose.yml` often will not include a `command:`.  This makes it easier to run the image in other contexts (via `docker run` without Compose; in Kubernetes) since you won't have to retype the command every different way you want to run the container.  The entrypoint wrapper pattern highlighted in [@sytech's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71942870) is very useful in general and it's easy to add to a container that uses a `CMD` without an `ENTRYPOINT`; but it requires the Dockerfile to use `CMD` as a normal well-formed shell command.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change `CMD` to `ENTRYPOINT`. And run the 1st script as daemon in the background using `&`.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker_entrypoint.sh"]
```

**docker_entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

exec python tests.py &
exec python main.py
```

Comment: thanks! by any chance, do you also know how I can achieve the same thing using docker-compose?

Comment: There is no reason to change `CMD` to `ENTRYPOINT`.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is a good rule of thumb that a container should only a single process and that essential process should be pid 1

Using an entrypoint can help you do multiple things at runtime and optionally run user-defined commands using `exec`, as according to the [best practices guide](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#entrypoint).

For example, if you always want the tests to run whenever the container starts, then execute the defined command in CMD.

First, create an entrypoint script (be sure to make it executable with `chmod +x`):

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# always run tests first
python /src/tests.py

# then run user-defined command
exec "$@"
```

Then configure the dockerfile to copy the script and set it as the entrypoint:

```
#...
COPY entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

Then when you build an image from this dockerfile and run it, the entrypoint will first execute the tests then run the command to run main.py

The command can also still be overridden by the user when running the image like `docker run ... myimage <new command>` which will still result in the entrypoint tests being executed, but the user can change the command being run.

Comment: thanks! by any chance, do you also know how I can achieve the same thing using docker-compose?

Comment: @x89 the behavior will be the same in docker-compose. Just specify the `image:` or `build:` key in the compose file to use this dockerfile/image. Using the `command:` or `entrypoint:` keys in your compose file, you can override the behavior as well (similar to the `--entrypoint` flag for `docker run` or providing a command at the end of `docker run`).

Comment: hmm as someone who hasn't used docker before, I am not so sure what you mean. If you see my compose.yml file, I am already specifying the image I created earlier with ```docker build```. How else could I modify it to work with the endpoint? A few steps explanation would be quite helpful

Comment: @x89 if you are using the dockerfile I have provided in this answer, in the compose.yml file you have in your post, simply remove the `command:` key and the duplicate `main:` key (you only need 1 service), then run `docker-compose up` (or `docker-compose run main` as you have).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating a bash script(let's name entrypoint.sh) which is containing the python commands. If you want, you can create background processes of those.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

python tests.py
python main.py
```

Edit your docker file as follows:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

# Create workDir
RUN mkdir code
WORKDIR code
ENV PYTHONPATH = /code

#upgrade pip if you like here
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy Code
COPY . .

RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

In the docker compose file, add the following line to the service.

```
entrypoint: [ "./entrypoint.sh" ]
```

Comment: thanks! by any chance, do you also know how I can achieve the same thing using docker-compose?

Comment: This doesn't need GNU bash, which Alpine-based images won't have; `#!/bin/sh` is fine.  This can keep using `CMD` which is easier to override, for example if you want to run just one of the scripts, there's no need to change it to `ENTRYPOINT`.  You do not need to also override it in the Compose file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this in your `docker-compose.yaml`?

```
version: '3'

services:
  main:
    image: free
    command: >
      /bin/sh -c 'python3 tests.py & && python3 main.py &'
```

both will run in the background

then run in terminal

```
docker-compose up --build
```